# Accessing the edit method from google play developer rest api

Tags: java, rest, google-play-developer-api

I successfully authenticated to google play developer rest api and I am getting also the refresh token but I can figure out how to make an edit requests.
I have method signature at the following link:

```
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/insert
```

I added the following header

```
Authorization:{{token_type}} {{access_token}}
```

but i cant figure out where to put the package name:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/packageName/edits
```

I putted `packageName` like above using get and also as post parameter and in both cases i am encountered "404 not found" error. 
Please help.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits/insert documentation says to supply the app id in place of packageName placeholder. Have you tried following the documentation?

Comment: I followed the documentation but i cant figure out how to make the request.

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/edits?id = packageid && expiryTimeSeconds = 20

GET https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/**packageName**/edits/**editId**
```

according to 
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/edits#methods

Comment: post without any parameter?? I will try tonight I will send you a feedback

Comment: i just added more cases possible for you.

Comment: I saw. but i cannot get the editid. I will send you a feedback tonight after I will test again

Answer (score 2):

Please verify if you have followed all steps for authentication and authorization as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/authorization).

Since you are not getting 401 or 403, you might be sending the token correctly.

To call the api:

put your package name as a path paramters and specify the edit resource in the body. Please note that the edit resource is ignored but needs to be provided.

send your request like this:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/yourPackageNameHere/edits
```

in the body:

```
{
  "id": "abcd",
  "expiryTimeSeconds": "asd"
}
```

make sure u provide content type in header as well.
Authorization is also required in the headers as you mentioned.

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: and what should I type at the body id instead of abcd ?

Comment: give any random string. the values are ignored, but still the fields are required to be given.